# Google Cloud Trace 192.168.1.1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-trace, google-cloud-stackdriver

In the Trace page of Google Cloud Console I can see address 192.168.1.1 which takes a lot of time to execute. What is this address? From where? Is it from internal cloud's infrastructure? Or is it mine local address (if it possible)?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talk with Google Cloud Support appears that 192.168.1.1 is exactly machine IP address on which Google Cloud Function is launched. But the interesting thing is that this address only appears if `console.*` things are in the code. So, for example I'm using `console.log` to log something with google cloud logging.

And on the screen shot there are several calls of this address. In the top we can see long living calls, this calls are with kept console.log connection. And, for example last call lasts only 3ms and immediately closed. This console.log has been called right in the end of the request.

Hope it might help someone.